# Put local variable in angular.forEach loop in the global

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I have created a variable inside the angular.forEach loop that I need outside the loop to bind to the $scope, but i don´t know how to get outside this variable miAlumno.

Thanks.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('jarciaApp')
    .controller('alumnoCtrl', function($routeParams, $firebaseArray) {

        var ref = firebase.database().ref('PrimeroA');

        var JarciaArray = $firebaseArray(ref);

        var id = $routeParams.id;

        var curso = $routeParams.curso;

        var miAlumno;


        JarciaArray.$loaded()
            .then(function(miAlumno) {
                angular.forEach(JarciaArray, function(alumno, miAlumno) {
                    if (alumno.Id == id) {
                        var miAlumno = alumno;
                    }
                })
            });

        console.log(miAlumno);
    });
```

Comment: Don't use `var` on the inner one (that's redefining `miAlumno`). But even that won't log the value where you have the `console.log`, since the `$loaded()` is asynchronous. You could just do `$scope.miAlumno` inside the loop, if you inject `$scope`.

Comment: I don´t inject the $scope because i´m using I don´t know how it called, 'as controller' ?  I bind data to the scope with this.variable = .... . But I can´t use it inside the loop because this is not the scope inside the loop.

Comment: Okay, then outside of the loop, add `var me = this;` and in the loop do `me.miAlumno = alumno;`.If you're speaking Spanish, maybe `var esto = this;` is better :).

Comment: That´s works Great. Thank you very much. I will try to use english in my code ;)-

Comment: Nice :). I've posted this as an answer. If it helps, take a look at the next steps in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare variable miAlumno in loop. Declare it outside and it will be visible. 
Pay attention at that console.log(miAlumno), it probably will be always null because of the asynchronous assignement.

Comment: I remove var key word inside the loop but my variable miAlumno outside the loop doesn´t recive the value of the inside loop.

Comment: the inside loop is asynchronous, so you have to be sure that you're checking the outside value only after the execution of the loop. Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are wanting to use the `alumno` variable you have passed into the function outside the scope of that function?

You can go about it by creating/declaring a global variable outside the function just as you did with `miAlumno`, then simply assign your global variable to the value your function produces. Also you have `miAlumno` declared twice, once outside as a global, then inside the for loop.

Apologies if I'm misunderstanding, and if so, please elaborate.

Comment: It that exacly i want but if a create a outside variable miAlumno and try to assing the alumno inside the loop to this global variable, anything happens. miAlumno remain as undefine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the `ControllerAs` syntax, which means what traditionally would be scope variables are automatically bound as properties of the controller. You can simply set the variable inside of the loop, using a cached value of `this`:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('jarciaApp')
    .controller('alumnoCtrl', function($routeParams, $firebaseArray) {

        var ref = firebase.database().ref('PrimeroA');

        var JarciaArray = $firebaseArray(ref);

        var id = $routeParams.id;

        var curso = $routeParams.curso;

        var me = this;

        JarciaArray.$loaded()
            .then(function() {
                angular.forEach(JarciaArray, function(alumno) {
                    if (alumno.Id == id) {
                        me.miAlumno = alumno;
                    }
                });
                // This will work to show the value
                console.log(me.miAlumno);
            });

        // This still won't work, since $loaded is asynchronous
        console.log(this.miAlumno);
    });
```

I've also removed the extra attempts to pass `miAlumno` to the `then` function and the callback for `forEach`; those are unnecessary.

Do note the comments about `console.log`. I believe the `$loaded()` is asynchronous; thus it will not be set until whatever process that is actually finishes. If you move the `log` to inside the `then()`, you'll see the result.